# rendering an array of objects with react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Actually what I'm trying to do is as followed:

I'm working with github API and I want to show the list of search result in Users component

after searching the result is appeared in the users state in redux However, in the UserItem component after console.log it returns undefined

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

I also created a **sandbox** for this project:
https://sh48l.csb.app

Comment: It might be the naming of your `users` store. check if it matches the one you are using in `mapStateToProps`, if it does, please [create a sandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/)

Comment: the sendbox is not working